# adding a new function has created an undefined variable

Tags: php, function, variables, undefined

I'm working on adapting a bit of PHP for a styleguide generator to pull in the .scss file and display it, but at line 56 I'm getting a notice: undefined variable.

The line in question is

```
$sass = 'sass'.strstr($path, "/");
```

and the whole functions.php is

```
<?php

  // Display title of each markup samples as a list item
  function listMarkupAsListItems ($type) {
    $files = array();
    $handle=opendir('markup/'.$type);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))):
        if(stristr($file,'.html')):
            $files[] = $file;
        endif;
    endwhile;

    sort($files);
    foreach ($files as $file):
        $filename = preg_replace("/\.html$/i", "", $file);
        $title = preg_replace("/\-/i", " ", $filename);
        $title = ucwords($title);
        echo '<li><a href="#sg-'.$filename.'">'.$title.'</a></li>';
    endforeach;
  }

  // Display markup view and source
  function showMarkup($type) {
    $files = array();
    $handle=opendir('markup/'.$type);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))):
        if(stristr($file,'.html')):
            $files[] = $file;
        endif;
    endwhile;

    sort($files);
    foreach ($files as $file):
        $filename = preg_replace("/\.html$/i", "", $file);
        $title = preg_replace("/\-/i", " ", $filename);
        $documentation = 'doc/'.$type.'/'.$file;
        echo '<div class="sg-markup sg-section">';
        echo '<div class="sg-display">';
        echo '<h2 id="sg-'.$filename.'" class="sg-h2">'.$title.'</h2>';
        if (file_exists($documentation)) {
          echo '<div class="sg-doc">';
          include($documentation);
          echo '</div>';
        }
        include('markup/'.$type.'/'.$file);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="sg-markup-controls"><button type="button" class="sg-btn sg-btn--source">View Source</button> <a class="sg-btn--top" href="#top">Back to Top</a></div>';
        echo '<div class="sg-source sg-animated">';
        echo '<button type="button" class="sg-btn sg-btn--select">Copy Source</button>';
        echo '<pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-markup">';
        echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('markup/'.$type.'/'.$file));
        echo '</code></pre>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        $sass = 'sass'.strstr($path, "/");
        $sass = str_replace(".html",".scss",$sass);
        if (file_exists($sass)) {
          echo '<div class="sg-sub-section">';
          echo '<div class="sg-markup-controls">';
          echo '<button type="button" class="sg-btn sg-btn--source">View Sass</button>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<div class="sg-source">';
          echo '<button type="button" class="sg-btn sg-btn--select">Copy Sass</button>';
          echo '<pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-scss">';
          echo file_get_contents($sass);
          echo '</code></pre>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
        }
    endforeach;
  }
?>
```

I'm sure this is some simple PHP issue I'm getting wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
The code for the $sass was taken from another snippet, looking at two comments (thank you) it seems the $path variable is the problem? I guess I need to define that to the folder path of where I'm looking?

Comment: where does the variable `$path` defined

Comment: Where you $path variable is defined?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $path first. You could do that elsewhere and call in the $path variable to your function with a line at the beginning of the function like:

```
function showMarkup($type) {
global $path;
// ... etc.
```

Or define a default for it when you define the function:

```
function showMarkup($type, $path="my-default-path/") {
```